# Why is swagger embedding v2/api-docs in request path for each resource

Tags: url, swagger, http-status-code-404

I can access swagger just fine and it is finding all of my resources (endpoints).  However, Try it out! fails on each link because the request path has v2/api-docs embedded within it.  The request constructed is as follows

https://{host}/{context-root}/v2/api-docs/{actual endpoint}

How do I go about configuring swagger to stop adding that to the request path?

Answer (score 0):

After chasing this around and re-configuring the Docket, a friend noticed I had two slashes in my browser URL

https://{host}//{context-root}/swagger-ui.html

Changing my own hand-typed url solved the issue!